# Error while eploying a ReportWebsite with Microsooft reporting tool

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config, microsoft-reporting

I am trying to deploy a website that has MicrosoftReport in it. When I deploy it I get the error on the client system a shown below:
[image]

Here is my code .aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>


        <table style="width:60%;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>


<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From Date : "></asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" 
    runat="server" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To Date : "></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtEndDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtEndDate">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="report.rdlc">
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I solve the problem? Do I have to add any reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/35936-Could-not-load-file-or-assembly.aspx

Solved my problem.